# How to disable only one thing (from user input) and keep the others running for 30 seconds?

Tags: python, timer

Let's say you are making a game and it has an input that asks you what do you want to do.

```
 bal=0
while True:
  question=input("What do you want to do?")
    if(input=="beg"):
      print(Adding 500$ to your balance.)
      bal=bal+500
    elif(input=="bal"):
      print("Balance: "+str(bal))
```

I want to make a timer so the user cannot use beg command for 30 seconds. But still be able to use other commands -I'll probably add more commands.
Btw I couldnt do indents here the website page went downward but imagine the while true loop and ifs has correct indent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the help of time module.

```
import time
bal=0
start = 0
while True:
  question=input("What do you want to do?")
    if(question=="beg"):
      if(time.time()-start>=30):
          print(Adding 500$ to your balance.)
          bal=bal+500
          start = time.time()
      else:
          print("Wait for",30-time.time()+start,"seconds")
    elif(question=="bal"):
      print("Balance: "+str(bal))
      time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I can continue using other commands (like bal) when beg is disabled right?

Comment: Yes, you can as it is independent.

Comment: Your answer is simply LEGENDARY!

Answer (score 0):

one approach, a dict with last time used (as you mention you will have more)

```
from time import time

def beg():
    # your code

commands = {
    "beg": {"func": beg, "last_time":0, "timeout": 30 }, #maybe more stuff
    "another": {"func": another, "last_time":0, "timeout": 10 },
    # ...
} # you are likely wanting to build this dict dynamically, maybe

while True:
    question = input("What do you want to do?")
    if question in commands:
        if time() > commands[question]["last_time"] + commands[question]["timeout"]:
            commands[question]["func"]() # this executes the function of the command
            commands[question]["last_time"] = time() # this sets the time as of now
        else: print(f"you are not allowed to use {question} yet") # you get the idea
    else: print("command not recognized") # yada
```